# query a graph by edge attribute using Igraph. Some easy way?

Tags: r, igraph

So I want to take the subgraph based on edges attributes (see example below). I found the way to do it but it turns out to be very verbose for such a simple task. I am using Igraph on R.

*example*:

Let's say I want to plot the sub-graph which has positive weighted edges. In the example below would be to eliminate the edges `b -> g` and `e -> a`

```
my_graph <- graph_from_data_frame(
  data.table( from   = c("a", "b", "c", "d", "e")
            , to     = c("g", "g", "g", "a", "a")
            , weight = c( 2,  -2 ,  3 ,  4 , -2)))

# This does the trick but... Should be easier isn't it?
positive_graph <- 
   subgraph.edges( my_graph
                 , E(my_graph)[E(my_graph)$weight >  0])
```

Comment: Why should this be easier? That doesn't look all that complex to me. It would probably be better to take your "answer" out of the question and post it as an answer below. If people have different solutions, they can post them as well and people can vote on the different solutions. Given the format of this site, it's odd to post a question that already has an answer.

Comment: @MrFlick Ok, maybe I haven't asked the best way. My problem is that when the query gets more complex I have troubles with It. Since graphs are subscriptable I expected some kind of easy accesors to attributes and subgraphs and i was assuming to not know that notation

Comment: It's pretty standard base R notation. I've started using `tidygraph`, which extends many of the `dplyr`-type functions to graphs, but that's not so much a solution as an alternative way of doing things